# JavaScript Scroll To Top of Parent DIV

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the following method to scroll to the position of a given page element, but it keeps scrolling me to the top of the page instead:

```
var $ = function(el) {
        return document.getElementById(el); 
}

var scrollToEl = (function(){
    var page = $('PageContainer'),
    headerHeight = $('FixedHeader').getBoundingClientRect().height;

    return function(el){
        if (typeof el !== 'object') return false; 

        // If a jQuery object, convert to raw DOM el
        if ('get' in el) el = el.get(0);

        // Outputs DOM element, 75, DOM element
        console.debug(page, headerHeight, el); 

        // Should scroll the page to the element's position, but goes to top...
        page.scrollTop = el.offsetTop - headerHeight; 
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var divs=document.getElementById('yourDivId');

    if(Boolean(divs.style.transform)){//for IE(10) and firefox 

     divs.style.transform='translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)'; 

    }else{//for chrome and safari
       divs.style['-webkit-transform']='translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)'; 

   }
```

This will let the div on the top position. hope this might help you.

Answer (score -1):

for $('PageContainer') use $('#PageContainer') or $('.PageContainer') depending on ID or class and same for  $('FixedHeader')

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but I am not using jQuery. I created the '$' function.